# Match GridView Cell and TextBox Value With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've a gridview with 5 columns including a TexBox in it. What I am trying is to give input to the TextBox inside the GridView and it should match a cell value of it. I am using JavaScript to do so. If the TextBox value matches the cell value, it should alert with a message 'Match found'. Here is a simple solution that I've tried:

```
var grid = document.getElementId("<%=GridView1.ClientID %>");

for(i = 0; i <= grid.rows.Length(); i++) {

    if(grid.rows.cells[3].value == grid.rows.cells[4].getElementTagName("INPUT")[0].value) 

}
```

The above code just fires the alert with 'Value does not match' all the time. I am hoping it could be done simply in the front-end and would be looking forward for some suggestions or ideas to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the console to log your values, so that you can follow what is going on in your code. For example: console.log('cell3: ' + grid.rows.cells[3].value + ',  cell4: ' + grid.rows.cells[4].getElementTagName("INPUT")[0].value); The console can be displayed using the F12 key in most browsers.

Comment: Your task definition is a bit unclear: what if there are 100 rows w/matches - should your Javascript code generate 100 alerts? Please clarify. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Right now there are ten rows. Yes, you could say so. It should alert for the matched rows individually.

Comment: Then the task definition/logic is a bit weird. Do you expect the User to click on the "OK" button 10 times? What would you achieve by implementing such functionality? Regards,

Comment: I am trying it with the OnChange event. If the rows are matched, then there would be no alert. If no match, then it should alert.